# Cannot Load Image in Spring Boot

Tags: html, image, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm making a sport e-commerce website using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf and in the index of products page and edit page of a particular product, I can't view the image of the product. [This is how the edit a product page (inspect on Chrome) looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30B7E.png)

Here's the HTML Code for Edit a product. The line below the current image is the one generating the error for both edit and index.

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Image:</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" th:name="file" th:id="file">
                <img class="mt-2" src="#" alt="" id="imgPreview1">
                <br><br>
                <label for="">Current image:</label>
                <img style="width: 100px;" th:src="@{'media/'+${product.image}}"> 
            </div>
```

I get the image from my media folder in src/main/resources/static/media and I get the product name from the database. There's no error in fetching the name of the image file from the database. It looks like a path error but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HTML` or `JSP` page are always in `../resources/templates/` and your image path is `../resources/static/media/`. To get image from `static` folder you have to go back using `../` from current folder and go to `media` folder which is inside `static` folder...

Change:

```
../resources/static/media/liverpool_21_22_home_kit.jpg
```

To:

```
../media/liverpool_21_22_home_kit.jpg
```

Comment: What you said didn't exactly work but I tinkered around with it and found the right code given below. <img style="width: 100px;" th:src="@{'../../media/' + ${product.image}}">

Comment: Faeem could you pls look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905786/entity-orm-design

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot, pages are searched under "templates" folder and resources are mapped under "static" folder by default. To access an image file under static folder, try

```
/image-path/image.ext
```

For example, I have an src folder under static and it has some image, logo.png then,

```
/src/logo.png
```

Comment: I've tried that. I've tried different variations of the path to no avail. Do you think is there some other way?

Comment: I had the same issue as you when I set up my server with spring boot. It is the default way the framework maps resources. The best way to check your resource location is to edit the resource path by developer mode in a browser and check for different paths for a sample resource.  You can find how to use developer mode on your browser here https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/what-is-chrome-developer-mode-what-are-its-uses/ (shown for Chrome as example)

Comment: have you tried putting "/" before media like th:src="@{'/media/'+${product.image}}

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. I've tried different paths to fix it but it doesn't work. But I think I might've found what's wrong. So when I enter the dev-tools page, when I hover around the image the link it shows is admin/products/edit/<edit id>/media/<image name>. Maybe if it pointed to src/main/resources/static/media/<image name> it might work. But I don't know how to do that