# Entity ORM design

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dto

I have four Entities , an Gorilla, a Health Check, Transmitter and a Microchip - I have a question about wiring these entities together.

Gorillas have Health Checks 3-4 times a year so they are OneToMany.
Each Gorilla *normally* has 1 microchip during the course of there life. Microchips are inserted during health checks, but usually only one unless one has fallen out (rare). So I make this OneToMany also on Gorilla to Microchip.
Each Gorilla has one Transmitter at a time, but they are replaced every year. So also OneToMany.

I have setup my entities like this:

**GORILLA**

```
@Data
public class Gorilla {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be null or empty")
    private String name;
   
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany (cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "gorilla")
    private List<Microschip> listMicroschip = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany (cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "gorilla")
    private List<Transmitter> listTransmitter = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "gorilla")
    private List<HealthCheck> listHealthCheck = new ArrayList<>();
```

**MICROCHIP**

```
@Data
public class Microchip {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be null or empty")
    private String code;
    private LocalDate dateInserted;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private Gorilla gorilla;
```

**HEALTHCHECK**

```
@Data
public class HealthCheck {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Gorilla gorilla;
    // other stuff
```

When viewing the gorilla entity as a list or a single i normally get the Gorilla with Name, *current* transmitter, current microchip and sometimes a list of summary fields for the health check.

When viewing a HealthCheck want to retrieve it with Gorilla details, any microchips or transmitters that were attached during that HealthCheck.

The problem with the current design with the Microchips and Transmitters having a relationship with the Gorilla is it makes it easy to get a Gorilla with its current (most recent) transmitter and (most recent) microchip.

This design however makes it hard to get a healthcheck and see which microchip or transmitter was attached on that healthcheck (if any were).

My code for getting the newest microchip for example is:

```
   default void helperMapping(Gorilla source, GorillaDTO target) {
        if (!source.getListTransmitter().isEmpty()) {
            Transmitter trans = (source.getListTransmitter()
                    .stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparing(Transmitter::getDateAttached)).get());
            target.setChannel(trans.getChannel());
            target.setChannelOffset(trans.getChannelOffset());
        }
```

How can I setup the ORM so that:

1. I don't have to stream over the list of Gorilla's transmitters/microchips each time I want the current one - seems very in-efficent.
2. I can retrieve a list of healthchecks with any microchips or transmitters relevant to that healthcheck
3. Less common get a list of all transmitters/microchips for a given Gorilla

(PS: I also tried microchip/transmitter sitting under HealthCheck but they made it even hard to get current microchip/transmitter)

**UPDATE**

I am considering having a two relationships:
Gorilla (One) to Transmitter (Many)
HealthCheck (One) to Transmitter (One and Optional)

This way I could easily find the newest Transmitter for any Gorilla (newest in list) and I can see which health check a transmitter was created in.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would have the relationships owned the one side and be uni-directional - so that e.g. `Microchip` owns the relationship and the `Gorilla` doesn’t care. I would then remove the lists from `Gorilla` and add [derived fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29004311/2071828) to get the current microchip/transmitter. I don’t think `Gorilla` should have anything about the `Healthcheck` - it makes little object modelling sense for the `Gorilla` to know that.

Comment: Why remove the list from Gorilla? When viewing a Gorilla I want to see a list of healthchecks.

Comment: Do _you_ know all your health checks? Their dates and details? No! Of course you don’t. You presumably log into a website to get the details - a “health check service” if you will…

Comment: Can you be more specific? You mean that the HealthChecks should be retrieved separate to a Gorilla (by the HCservice and the DTO constructed?

Comment: Chat is here @BoristheSpider https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/243985/entity-orm-design?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

I was misunderstanding. If Transmitter and Microchip are only changed during healthcheck, how about this approach?

#### Gorilla

```
@Data
public class Gorilla {
    
    @OneToOne // unidirectional
    private Microchip currentMicroChip

    @OneToOne // unidirectional
    private Transmitter currentTransmitter

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "gorilla")
    private List<HealthCheck> listHealthCheck = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### MICROCHIP

```
@Data
public class Microchip {
   
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private HealthCheck healthCheck;
```

#### HEALTHCHECK

```
@Data
public class HealthCheck {

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany (cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "gorilla")
    private List<Microschip> listMicroschip = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany (cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "gorilla")
    private List<Transmitter> listTransmitter = new ArrayList<>();
   
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Gorilla gorilla;
```

Comment: So instead of pulling them all back with the parent entity you have a query for pulling back the newest given a Gorilla id as a param?

Comment: Yeah, I think this is most performance-efficient way with keeping current structure

Comment: If you see my update you can see I am open to changing the structure.

Comment: In my opinion I'm not recommend changing structure to that because it makes hard to find specific Gorilla's all Transmitter list and after some time your teammates or you might be wonder why this relationship is set to one-to-one

Comment: At the moment how would you find which Transmitter was associated with a given health check?

Comment: I edited answer

Comment: Shouldnt the relationships on HealthCheck be OneToOne? Only one transmitter can be attached, and one microchip attached during a healthcheck?

Comment: Its the healthcheck to microchip/transmitter that is OneToOne.

Comment: Sure, you can change it to bidirectional OneToOne